# class "javax.persistence.TypedQuery"'s signer information does not match signer information of other classes in the same package

Tags: hibernate

**I came to know that this error comes when a class is being loaded from two different jars. but in my case how to know list of JAR containing "javax.persistence.TypedQuery" class, so that I can remove one of them to solve the issue.**

```
java.lang.SecurityException: class "javax.persistence.TypedQuery"'s signer information does not match signer information of other classes in the same package**
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.checkCerts(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.preDefineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2957)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1210)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1690)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2957)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1210)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1690)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:571)
        at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:488)
        at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:474)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.determineCandidateConstructors(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:241)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineConstructorsFromBeanPostProcessors(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1065)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1038)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:755)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:663)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:629)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:677)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:548)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:489)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
        at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1284)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1197)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1087)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5266)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5554)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    Dec 05, 2017 1:41:29 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext loadOnStartup**
```

Comment: check you Pom.xml and dependency Hierarchy Tab.. after that if you found the jar.. just exclude it

Comment: Thanks for reply, I am not using maven how to check.Please help...

Comment: then what you are using ? any build tool ?

Comment: I guess you need some sort of script/tool for this. What is your programming environment?Win/Lin?Eclipse etc...

Comment: Windows 10 OS and Eclipse.

Comment: "javax.persistence.TypedQuery" class is available in hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar but I don't know why I am getting error. Please help...